# refresh photo in menu - ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, data-binding

I am doing that

$rootScope.img= "http://graph.facebook.com/" + success.authResponse.userID + "/picture?type=large";

and i have that on the lateral menu

```
 <a class="item item-avatar" data-componentid="html9" style="
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;">
             <img  ng-model="avatar" ng-src="{{ img }}" style="max-width: 50px; max-height: 50px;">

</a>
```

the problem is when i get login and get the image from facebook, it doesnt refresh on the view.

Comment: Are you injecting $rootScope in your controller?

Comment: yes, of course. if hadn´t done it i would have had a compiling error

Answer (score 0):

Making a [research on the official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus), I found this solution:

```
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
     var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
     $rootScope.img= "http://graph.facebook.com/" + uid + "/picture?type=large";
   } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
     // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
     // but has not authenticated your app
   } else {
     // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
   }
 });
```

`FB.getLoginStatus()` allows you to determine if a user is logged in to Facebook and has authenticated your app.